# dashing / gridster - making one widget immovable

Tags: widget, gridster, dashing

can i define one widget (lets say a the Top one) to be immovable?

i'm using shopify/dashing from github

i'm new to Dashing and gridster interface so i don't really know how to approach the problem

Answer (score 2):

Itay Sela,

It does not look like gridster supports that feature right now. Here is issue #130 for Gridster which is a feature request to make something immovable. It looks like it is still open, however a few different approaches are discussed in the thread that may help you implement it on your own.

https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/130